# Nice shadow effect in text (UISegmentedControl)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I would like to bring some color to the texts of my UISegmentedControl. So, I've searched a bit about this topic, but it seems to be not possible out-of-the-box.

But I found this nice blog post ([link text](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=234)), how to build an image out of a custom text and then assign it to the segemented control. Works fine, but the text in these created images do not have this nice little shadow effect as the original ones.

So, does anyone know, how to create such a shadow effect? I guess, Apple does the same (building an image for the text) with the standard segmenented control.

Thanks for your help.

Regards
Matthias

Comment: check out this http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/19/iphone-devsugar-create-shiny-buttons-easily/ and here: http://tapadoo.com/2010/tired-of-trying-to-create-nice-buttons-for-your-iphone-app-try-this/, it is a hack that works only in the iPhone Simulator, but you can use this program to save the glassy buttons as images to your filesystem and use them as a background image of your UIButtons later in your real app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I would like to have the effect for the text. Not for the button itself.